# Gradle command line arguments to override properties in build.gradle

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, command-line-arguments

Whenever an existing android project is imported, in most cases we need to change values following with our installed tools version number

in project/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'
    }
}
```

in project/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion xx
    buildToolsVersion "xx.x.x"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app.xyz"
        minSdkVersion xx
        targetSdkVersion xx
        versionCode x
        versionName "x.x"
    }
...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:x.xx'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:xx.x.x'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:xx.x.x'
}
```

how to override above values of

```
classpath
compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion
targetSdkVersion
```

using command line argument e.g.

```
./gradlew installDebug -PCompileSdkVersion=26 -PbuildToolsVersion=26.0.0
```

or something like this?

My idea is to use one same command (with my installed sdk version numbers as arguments) to build any project not maintained by me.

it is helpful if we have to build multiple projects which are managed by others.it can save much time by overriding their build configuration by ours through command line args so that we do not need to change it every time by going at particular location in each newly imported project.

Answer (score 10):

Put in your `gradle.properties` default value:

```
SDK_VERSION=26
```

Use in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion project.getProperties().get("SDK_VERSION")
}
```

Use: `./gradlew build -PSDK_VERSION=26`

PS: Don't forget, that you must change support libraries major version also.

Comment: thanks for your help. but my scenario is to build 10 or more different project downloaded from github. All have different build config. I need a one command with arguments of my installed tools version no. so that one command is sufficient to build 10 or more project without changing it's build.gradle file.

Comment: I have also edited my question for better explaination

Comment: When you are asking where the `-P` (--project-prop) prefix came from have a look to the [gradle docu](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#environment_options)