# How to pass argument in Android Test class using command line?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I want a way to send command line parameters to my Test class for running all Unit tests and create Test coverage report out of it.
I am using below command to generate Test coverage report and passing parameters

```
./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport -Dparam=input1
```

And below is app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testcoverageapp"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }

    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()
            test {
                println systemProperties['param']
                systemProperties(System.getProperties())
            }
        }
    }



    tasks.withType(Test){
        systemProperties=System.properties
        println systemProperties['param.name']
        systemProperty 'param.name', System.getProperty('param')
    }
    
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    testImplementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.3.2'
}
```

And I am using below method to access the command line arguments.

```
val uName : String? = System.getProperty("param")
if(uName !=null){
    Log.d("ExampleInstrumentedTest", "Argument  param: " + uName)
}
```

But, the command line arguments are not received in Test file and it is printing null in logs.

```
/com.example.testcoverageapp D/ExampleInstrumentedTest: Argument  param: null
```

I tried many online articles for receiving the command line arguments inside test file but may be I am missing something. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

I found below method to pass command line parameter to the Android Test files.
Ref : [Gradle command line arguments to override properties in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051593/gradle-command-line-arguments-to-override-properties-in-build-gradle)

**Step 1:** Create a parameter tobe passed in gradle.properties file

```
TEST_PARAM1=param1
TEST_PARAM2=param2
```

**Step 2:** Add entry of the parameter in app build.gradle file inside defaultconfig and add reference of param name from gradle.properties file.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "TEST_PARAM1", "\"$TEST_PARAM2\""
        buildConfigField "String", "TEST_PARAM2", "\"$TEST_PARAM2\""
    }
```

**Step 3:** Build the test project, so BuildConfig.java is created with default values in it.

```
public static final String TEST_PARAM1 = "param1";
  public static final String TEST_PARAM2 = "param2";
```

**Step 4:** Now run your test coverage command( or any other gradle command) with -P and param like shown below

```
 ./gradlew createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport -PTEST_PARAM1=param_value1 -PTEST_PARAM2=param_value2
```

With above command the BuildConfig.java will automatically update to below changes.

```
public static final String TEST_PARAM1 = "param_value1";
public static final String TEST_PARAM2 = "param_value2";
```

**Step 5:** Now access the parameters created in BuildConfig.java in the test file you want shown below.

```
val uName : String? = BuildConfig.TEST_PARAM1
val uPASS : String? = BuildConfig.TEST_PARAM2
```

Hope this helps to anybody stumble upon here. Thanks.