# How to Dynamically Create or Set a BuildConfigField for Android Studio Using Gradle Command Line

Tags: android, gradle, command-line, parameters, arguments

I know how to create a buildConfigField variable and set its value in my `build.gradle` file. E.g. `buildConfigField 'String', 'BUILD_VALUE', 'HELLO WORLD'`.

I also know how to pass in an argument from gradle command line via task. For instance, if I do `./gradleW propertyTypes -Dargs=test1 -Pargs=test2` in terminal and have the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
task propertyTypes(){
    doLast{
        if (project.hasProperty("args")) {
            println "Project property ["+project.getProperty("args")+"]"
        }
        println "System property ["+System.getProperty("args")+"]"
    }
}
```

it will output `test2` and `test1` to terminal.

However, I don't know how to put them together. I want to be able to pass in an argument (e.g. "Hello World") via the gradle commandline and then have that set as a buildConfigField for use in the program itself. When I try though, either task doesn't know what a buildConfigField is or the buildConfigField doesn't know the properties passed into the task.

Any insight on how I can make this work?

Comment: `android { android.applicationVariants.all { variant -> variant.buildConfigField "String", 'BUILD_VALUE', "\"${getArgsValueSomehow()}\"" } }`  where `getArgsValueSomehow` returns some string ?

Comment: Yes, that is the part I'm not sure how to write. The `getArgsValueSomehow`-ness of it.

Comment: https://www.groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65150777/5026136

To paraphrase:

**Step 1:** Create a variable to hold the default value in the gradle.properties file

`MY_VAR=defaultValue`

**Step 2:** Create a `buildConfigField` variable called [VAR_NAME] in the app's build.gradle file inside the `android->defaultconfig` block. For its value, give it the variable you put in `gradle.properties` using the syntax below:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "VAR_NAME", "\"$MY_VAR\""
    }
```

**Step 3:** Rebuild the project. (Until you do, you won't be able to access the new BuildConfig variable in your code.)

**Step 4:** Use the `BuildConfig.VAR_NAME` variable in your app's code as desired.

**Step 5:** Pass a new value for the variable via command line by adding the following flag to your `gradlew` command line:

`-P MY_VAR=new_value`

where `new_value` is whatever you decide and `MY_VAR` is the name you put in your gradle.properties file.

---

As an added bonus, you can check that you are indeed able to pass in a value via command line and have it update correctly by adding the following to your app's `build.gradle` (just prior to the `android` block):

`task output { println "\"$MY_VAR\"" }`

(Note that "output" is just a name for the task --- you can call it anything)

Then if you run `./gradleW output` in terminal, it will print the default value for `MY_VAR` as you've set it in `gradle.properties.`

If instead you run `./gradleW output -P MY_VAR=new_val` then it will print the updated value!

Comment: I'm getting the error `Cause: defaultConfig contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled. To enable the feature, add the following to your module-level build.gradle: android.buildFeatures.buildConfig true`. Any idea why the feature is disabled by default?